# Java: The import org.apache.commons.lang cannot be resolved [Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been handed a java project for modification, so I went ahead and decided to set it up in my MacBook. I loaded the project into Eclipse (Luna), imported and added all the external jars necessary, and pretty much tried to copy the old setup.

Then, I get this:
[image: Marco]

Which is weird, because I could've sworn I added that as a JAR (same one from the old setup):
[image: Polo]
Oh, wait. There it is.

Now, according to [this, which may or may not apply, as it is NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381095/package-org-apache-commons-lang-does-not-exist-netbeans) (not sure if there's much of a difference), I should use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;`

Which, however, gives me this:

[image]

EDIT: Here's the part of the code that uses the StringEscapeUtils:
[image]

Sorry if this seems trivial, but I'm kinda stumped. Can anyone help? Thanks.

EDIT: It would appear that in trying to solve this problem, I ran into a different one. After changing the `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;` into `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;`, I noticed the error also says `Unable to load realm info from SCDynamic store`.

At this point, I'm not sure if I did solve the previous error, or not, as I probably need to fix this new error to proceed.

Comment: Please show the full code sample, especially where are you calling StringEscapeUtils' methods !

Comment: Make an explicit entry in .classpath file for this particular jar by opening project in navigator view.

Comment: Add this line in .classpath file of your project '<classpathentry kind="lib" path="path of the jar in your system"/>'

Comment: @jchampemont, I added a picture. Hope that's enough.

Comment: @PrakharAsthana, I found this there: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/lanceguinto/eclipse_jars/Gracenote/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>

Comment: @zack_falcon Go to "Java Build Path" of the project through properties and check in "Order and Export" whether the jar is checked there or not. If not checked, check it and the clean and build the project.

Comment: i'm facing like this problem, how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately or unfortunately your other libraries require an older version of your commons lang. That is, other libraries (like hadoop) may have a dependency on apache commons 2 library  So include the older version commons-lang-2.x version library and it should work fine.

Check this Apache Hadoop dependency link:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/dependency-analysis.html

There is a dependency on commons-lang version 2.6. So include that library in your eclipse classpath

Comment: Also, do not forget to restart your server once you have imported new jar files. The above worked for me upon restarting my server.